# "No module named x" for user-defined modules in Python deployment using Dockerfile and docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to deploy a Python app as a Docker container using Dockerfile and docker-compose.

The project structure is this:

```
ms-request
    - src
        __init__.py
        - exceptions
            __init__.py
            ms_request_exceptions.py
        - messaging
            __init__.py
            receive_rabbit.py
            send_rabbit.py
        - request
            __init__.py
            bsrequest.py
    - test
        __init__.py
        test_bsrequest.py
    Dockerfile
    requirements.txt
```

In my `receive_rabbit.py` script, I am importing functions from the request and messaging packages like so:

```
from src.request import bsrequest
from src.messaging.send_rabbit import send_message
```

Executing this using PyCharm works fine. Running it from the command line initially didn't work, until I updated the PYTHONPATH using `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:.`.

I would like to deploy this as a Docker container, so I created a Dockerfile and an entry in my docker-compose.yml for the project.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /bsreq
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY src/ ./src
COPY test/ ./test
RUN export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:.
CMD [ "python", "/bsreq/src/messaging/receive_rabbit.py" ]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
        rabbitmq: [...]
        bs-request:
                build: ./ms-request/
                depends_on:
                        - rabbitmq
                env_file:
                        - rabbit.env
        [...]
```

Running this using `docker-compose up bs-request` always ends in a crash with the error `No module named 'src'`.

I have tried multiple variations of inputs for the WORKDIR, COPY, PYTHONPATH and CMD lines in the Dockerfile. All lead to the same error. I've tried relative imports, which throw `Attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

I hope this is an issue others have encountered before. What do I need to do to get this deployment working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker layers-way building an image makes your `export` unusable right after the associated `RUN` command.

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /bsreq
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY src/ ./src
COPY test/ ./test
RUN export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:.  #--> exporting
CMD [ "python", "/bsreq/src/messaging/receive_rabbit.py" ]  #--> last export is not persistent
```

as a workaround you set environment variables that will persist through the build AND in the final image with `ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:.` command.
extra read: https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-time-env-values/

any how, suggested method is to write a `setup.py` file and install your package with `python setup.py install` so it would be installed as a package and imports would work.

P.S
a better, more updated way would be to use tools such as `poetry` that uses `pyproject.toml` (according to PEP 518, 517) which the future way of python!
bonus read: https://python-poetry.org/

good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is almost like three answers in one. I will be updating the project to use Poetry!